# Query a database and insert if not present

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to add a way to see if an entry is already in a connected database in the following code. If it is then don't add the entry and pop up a dialog saying something to the effect of `"already been scanned"` and if it is not, proceed as usual.

```
Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False"), _
    cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [XXXXX] (TrackingNumber, Date) SELECT @TrackingNumber, @Date WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM([XXXXX])WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber AND Date = @Date)", connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrackingNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TrNum
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8).Value = TrDate
        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My VB.NET might be somewhat off but hopefully this should give the general idea!

```
Dim rowsAffected AS Integer

    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False"), _
        cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [XXXXX] (TrackingNumber, Date) SELECT @TrackingNumber, @Date WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [XXXXX] WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber)", connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrackingNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TrNum
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8).Value = TrDate
        connection.Open()
        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
    End Using


If rowsAffected = 0 Then
MsgBox "Scanned Already"
Else
MsgBox "Inserted Succesfully"
End If
```

Comment: @Martin Smith One more quick thing, any reason this will not allow letters and only numbers to be entered?

Comment: @0bfus I can't see any reason why that would be the case. @TrackingNumber is varchar(50) so should allow letters. Does it give you an error?

Comment: @Martin Smith It allows one entry but it stores it in the database as a blank entry with a date and if you try any other entry it says it's inserted succesfully. very odd.

Comment: @0bfus - I'd try putting a break point on `cmd.Parameters.Add("@TrackingNumber",...` to check nothing else in your code is messing with `TrNum` and if that doesn't shed any light run SQL Profiler to see the statement actually being sent.

Comment: @Martin Smith Not sure what i did but it works fine for some reason now. Thanks again.

Comment: @Martin Smith Do you by any chance know how to make a result from a SELECT query display in a MsgBox?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put your inputs into a subquery that checks for redundancy:

```
INSERT INTO [XXXXXXX] (TrackingNumber, Date) 
    SELECT @TrackingNumber, @Date from DUAL 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM [XXXXXXX]
        WHERE TrackingNumber = @TrackingNumber AND Date = @Date)
```

Comment: I get an SqlException was unhandled error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery for the invalid object name DUAL. where in the original code would a sub query be put?

Comment: @0bfus - For SQL Server just delete the `from DUAL` you can get rows affected as the return value of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`. If zero nothing was changed.

Comment: Using the code above i get an sql exception was unhandled error at the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() saying incorrect syntax near ). i updated the code in my question to show the changes i have so far.

Comment: You don't need the brackets here `SELECT * FROM([XXXXX])`

Comment: alright another error at the same point once the brackets are out and it says "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_XXXXX'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.XXXXX'. The statement has been terminated." so it sees its a duplicate but now it needs to alert the user it is a duplicate and also not crash the app lol

Comment: @0bfus - If you use @Martin in your comment I'll be aware that you replied! What is the PK of the table?

Comment: @Martin Smith the trackingnumber is and also thanks, new here. should i make a new column in the table that auto increments and make that the primary?

Comment: @Obfus - No just remove ` AND Date = @Date` from the WHERE clause. Matthew must have assumed that was part of the PK.

Comment: @Martin Smith alright it no longer throws any errors but it also does not tell me it has already been enetered , is there a way?